# Postgres Concatenation

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to a simple concatenation in PostgreSQL and it keeps up throwing up an error message. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

```
select concat('abcde', 'fgh');
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

select concat(cast('abcde' as text), cast('fgh' as text));
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I am using Postgres version 8.4.11. Please let me know what is going on.

Comment: Check out the docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-string.html

Comment: Just so you know, if you want to list functions or search them, use the psql `\df` command. For example, to list all functions named `concat` use `\df concat` . For all functions in the `pg_catalog` schema (built-in functions) use `\df pg_catalog.` . For all functions with names *starting with* `concat` use `\df concat*`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The concat operator is `||`, so `select 'abcde' || 'fgh'` should work. Also, as @jonathan.cone suggested, [check out the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-string.html).

Answer (score 14):

`concat` was added in 9.1, it doesn't exist in 8.4. As others have noted, use the `||` operator.

Compare the [8.4 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-string.html) to the [9.1 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) and you'll notice that the `concat` function isn't present in the 8.4 docs.

See that bar at the top of the docs that says "This page in other versions" ? It's really handy when you're working with an old version, or if you find a link to an old version of a page via Google and you're on a newer version. Always make sure you're looking at the docs for the right version.

It'd be nice if the tables for functions etc included a "First appeared in version " - but unfortunately they don't.

If you're ever confused about the availablilty of a function, you can use `\df` in psql to list and search functions.

For example, to list all functions named `concat` use `\df concat`

For all functions in the `pg_catalog` schema (built-in functions) use `\df pg_catalog.` - note the trailing period, telling psql you mean "any function within the schema pg_catalog" not "the function named pg_catalog".

For all functions with names starting with `concat` use `\df concat*`

It's a very powerful tool. The same language works when searching for schema (`\dn`), tables (`\dt`), etc.

Comment: How does concat function automagically convert a date field to string ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'abcde' || 'fgh';

select cast('abcde' as text) || cast('fgh' as text);
```